# Заданные размеры инструмента "Рамка"

Tags: photoshop

Можно ли как-то в инструменте Ps "Рамка" в соотношении 1:1 квадрат, задать изначально ширину и высоту, а не растягивать?

Answer (score 0):

Нет.
Можно написать скрипт, который будет это делать, но, к сожалению, у Фотошопа плохая эргономическая модель вызова скриптов, поэтому проще по-быстрому растянуть, нежели делать кучу пассов руками и мышью, чтобы вызвать скрипт.